# why isn't jquery executing once page loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have this code to run once the page has loaded on the class unseen however its not working. It doesn't execute.

When i copy and paste it into my browser with the "javascript:" part at the start it works perfectly, what's going wrong?

I hope someone can help

```
$(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {  $('.unseen').css('border','2px solid #ffffff'); }, 600);        
 });
```

Thanks lots

Jake

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Are you sure you are including the jQuery script? And, are you sure it's not running? Put an `alert()` before the setTimeout and see if it fires.

Comment: It probably works as Ariel suggested. Is there any chance you are missing it because it's a white border? :)

Comment: the alert doesnt work inside of $(function() { }

Comment: @Jake, does the JavaScript console display a syntax error?

Comment: I'm using notepad++ and safari so can not see any errors.

Comment: This doesnt work: $(function() {alert('test'); });

Comment: @JakeStainer what version of jQuery are you using? Do you have other libraries on the page? does `jQuery(function() { alert('a') })` work ?

Comment: @Jake http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/PrototypingYourWebsite/PrototypingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH7-SW2

Comment: ive fixed it now, i just removed the function and just put the code at the bottom of my page and changed .unseen  to div.unseen and now works, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yLDbT/5/)

Works for me. You realise `#ffffff` is white, right?

**Fun fact:** You don't need jQuery

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.unseen'), function(v) {
            v.style.border = '2px solid black';
        });
    }, 600);
}, false);
```